# strange behavior of stdout redirected to a pipe

Tags: c, linux

Here is a minimal example demonstrating my problem. I have a program forking a new subprocess and redirecting stdout to it. It works fine. Then I fork a second subprocess and redirect stdout to it and I close the first pipe. I would expect that the first subprocess receives EOF in its input pipe and terminates. Instead it remains in reading state until the main task exits. I do not understand why. I would expect the first pipe to be closed and the first child process to become a zombie.

Here is the code demonstrating the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int popenin(char *command) {
    int                 pin[2];
    pid_t               pid;

    if (pipe(pin) != 0) exit(1);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) exit(1);

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pin[1]);
        dup2(pin[0], 0);
        close(pin[0]);
        execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", command, NULL);
        perror("Error:");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        close(pin[0]);
        return(pin[1]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int fd;
    fd = popenin("gzip > foo1.gz");
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
    printf("foo 1 content\n");fflush(stdout);
    fd = popenin("gzip > foo2.gz");
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);
    printf("foo 2 content\n");fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10000);
}
```

This program creates two files foo1.gz and foo2.gz, both empty and there are two gzip processes running in the system. I'd expect to see the first file completed, closed and the first gzip process to exit.

If I modify the minimal example in the following way, it works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int popenin(char *command) {
    int                 pin[2];
    pid_t               pid;

    if (pipe(pin) != 0) exit(1);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) exit(1);

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pin[1]);
        dup2(pin[0], 0);
        close(pin[0]);
        execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", command, NULL);
        perror("Error:");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        close(pin[0]);
        return(pin[1]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int fd;
    fd = popenin("gzip > foo1.gz");
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
    printf("foo 1 content\n");fflush(stdout);
    close(1);                    // close(1) is moved before popenin
    fd = popenin("gzip > foo2.gz");
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);
    printf("foo 2 content\n");fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10000);
}
```

Can somebody explain why the first version does not work?

Comment: Why are you using `dup()` after the second `popenin()`? After the first `popenin()` you used `dup2()`, which is the sane way of doing it.

Comment: The behavior is the same with `dup2`. The `dup` is there because then I can create the second example from the first one by moving a single line of code.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Not in general (you might be thinking of `fflush(stdin)`).  But in this case, the code has previously closed and reopened fd 1 (by using `dup2`).  I wouldn't say it's UB because the C standard doesn't know anything about `dup2`, but it's probably not the right way to do this - the stdio subsystem certainly isn't expecting to have its fds moved around behind its back.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't think that `fflush(stdout)` is UB. Anyway, the problem persists if you use `write` instead of `printf` and `fflush`.